# chrome extensions Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

chrome extensions
Error in the event handler: TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')

Hi all I wish to send text to a Textarea field by clicking a button or right-clicking on the page in Chrome but receive the above error.

I have this working on "other sites" where the Textarea is empty using chrome.tabs.sendMessage ,  and from looking up the process I understand what it means when the DOM has not loaded.

I can  set the value by using the Chrome console  and its works ok
document.getElementById("coverLetter").value('hello world')

here is some of my code

background.js =

var hello_World =  'hello_World'

```
function Shipped (info, tab) {
  if (info.editable) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    "text": hello_World
    });
  } 
}
```

(This works as normal)  but will not work on some pages,
I have two sites this will not work on upworks + people hour

what could be the problems here?

Comment: It means the element appears after your code has run. Use MutationObserver or 
simply setTimeout.

Comment: But how would you set this ..?